# Unable to connect to 802.1x network using NetworkManager on Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, wifi-configuration, networkmanager, 802.1x

For the past few days, I have been trying to get my Fedora 22 desktop and laptop to connect to my university's 802.1x WiFi network. However, I have been running into an issue.

Whenever I try using the NetworkManager GUI in GNOME to connect to the network, it will prompt me to authenticate using my credentials. I set the Authentication to PEAP, Inner Authentication to MSCHAPv2, and I tell it that a CA certificate is not required. I also type in my user account and password. After typing that information in, it will attempt to connect to the network, and then it will continually prompt me over and over in a popup window for my username and password (which are already filled in using the info I originally typed). I have double- and triple-checked that my account information is in fact correct.

To troubleshoot this, I found [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2168015) on the Ubuntu Forums regarding the same issue, and for some users, removing the `system-ca-certs` line from the config file resolved their issue. I tried looking for configuration files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, but I did not have any files located there. Instead, I tried using `nmcli` to manually edit the setting, and I ran `sudo nmcli connection modify ritwpa2 802-1x.system-ca-certs false`. However, that also did not work even after reloading the connection.

Finally, I found a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1167455) on the Red Hat Bugzilla about a similar issue in terms of a specific kernel release on Fedora 21; however, it seems like the issue has been resolved for most users now, but my issue remains. My kernel version is `4.1.5-200.fc22.x86_64`.

Are there any suggestions or ideas about how to resolve this? If any additional information is required, I'd be happy to provide if asked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/rit/comments/3i8h2h/unable_to_connect_to_ritwpa2_using_networkmanager/cue6xn2), a user found that the issue was with v2.4 of `wpa_supplicant`. Downgrading to v2.3 via dnf immediately resolved the issue and I was able to connect. I plan on reporting this as a bug to the wpa_supplicant team soon.